# Local computer Policies via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, policy

I am working on a C++ code that uses OpenLocalMachineGPO to add a registry key to set a theme for all its users. OpenLocalMachineGPO opens the default GPO for the computer.

I intend to do the same via Powershell cmdlets, but I cant understand the way to get to the default GPO for the machine as in the above C++ code. Get-GPO seems to work only on Group Policies over domains or sites. I couldn't find a way to set the Local Computer Policy, which is shown by the Local Group Policy Editor.

Comment: You haven't made a question, please clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the right way using PowerShell is to do that accessing the registry drives. You'll find here-under a way to mount `HKUSERS` one, the place were you'll find `.DEFAULT` for your theme.

```
PS C:\Users\JPB> $hkusers = New-PSDrive -Name HKUSERS   -PSProvider Registry -Root Registry::HKEY_USERS
PS C:\Users\JPB> cd hkusers:
PS C:\Users\JPB> dir .DEFAULT


    Hive: HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT


SKC  VC Name                           Property
---  -- ----                           --------
  9   0 Control Panel                  {}
  0   2 Environment                    {TEMP, TMP}
  4   0 EUDC                           {}
  3   0 Keyboard Layout                {}
  4   0 Printers                       {}
  9   0 Software                       {}
  1   0 SYSTEM                         {}
```